# How to isolate an integer in a QString

Tags: qt, g-code

I have a QString of Gcode that will look like this:

```
T<some number> <and anything might come after it>
```

Currently, I'm using `myString.midRef(1,1).toInt()` to get the digit I want (I don't care about the rest of the line). However, this will not work if there is a two digit number, like so:

```
T12 ;blah blah blah
```

**Is there a good / better way of doing this other than searching index by index to see where the number stops?**

- There will always be a `T` in front of the number.
- There will always be a semicolon after the number if there is any other text after it, but there may not be a space in between the number and the semicolon.
- There may or may not be anything after the number at all.

Comment: there you have it. use the semicolon as a delimiter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regular expression to extract the number pattern, e.g.

```
int ib, ie, n;
QStringRef num;
ib = str.indexOf(QRegExp("T\\d+(\\s*;{1}.|$)"));
if (ib >= 0) {
    ib++;
    ie = str.indexOf(";", ib);
    n = ie >= ib ? ie - ib : -1; 
    num = str.midRef(ib, n);
}
```

Notes:

1. `T\d+` match a pattern begins with `T` followed by one or more digit.
2. `\s*;{1}.|$` match zero or more white spaces followed by semicolon plus any character **OR** exactly none in the last character.

Please note that in the above rule, `"T123 "` or `"T123\n"` won't match the pattern. If you want to allow white space, use the following:

```
QRegExp("T\\d+\\s*(;{1}.|$)")
```